# Fabric.js/Angular - When I change the image of a canvas object, it disappears and then reappears

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, fabricjs

What I want to do:

1. Select the object on the canvas
2. Click change image to change the selected image on the canvas

What is happening:

1. Image disappears, but reappears as the new image when you try to move the empty area.

I have no idea why it's doing this.  I assume its some sort of re-compiling of the DOM that has to be instantiated from the controller but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.  The jsfiddle demonstrates the problem but I've shown the code below as well.

```js
angular.module('canvasApp', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){

 $scope.up = function(){
  $scope.$broadcast('change');
 }

})



.directive('ngCanvas', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: true,
  template: '<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" data-drop="true" jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:\'drop(event, data, obj)\'}" ></canvas>',
  controller: function($scope){
   
   $scope.$on('change', function(event){
    var tmp = $scope.canvas.getActiveObject();
    
    var el = tmp.getElement();
    
    el.setAttribute('src', "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/7b3SLVgR65Fx4Q8JZyxQ");

    $scope.canvas.renderAll();
    $scope.canvas.calcOffset();
   });  

  },
  link:  function(scope, element, attrs){

   scope.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   
   fabric.Image.fromURL("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/jGVMrkPuQ8eNGn5BpsiB", function(oImg) {
    scope.canvas.add(oImg);
   });
  }

 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.13/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="canvasApp">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <button id="click" ng-click="up()">Change Image</button>

 <div ng-canvas></div>
 
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eg4y6d3k/4/

**EDIT**

If this same code is done as straight JS, without angular, it still has the same issue.  Code below.

```js
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

  fabric.Image.fromURL("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/jGVMrkPuQ8eNGn5BpsiB", function(oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
  });

  var up = function() {
    var tmp = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var el = tmp.getElement();

    el.setAttribute('src', "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/7b3SLVgR65Fx4Q8JZyxQ");

    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.13/fabric.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="click" onclick="up()">Change Image</button>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
```

Comment: Add `$scope.$digest()` after `canvas.renderAll()`

Comment: Tried both $digest() and $apply(), don't work.  They'll both give you errors bc you try to call them during a $on() cb.

Comment: True - I didn't check the console for errors but it did show the next image. Actually, now I can't repro even that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to fiddle a bit with fabric.js and canvas - never used it before.

Here's how I made this work:

```
$scope.$on('change', function(event, data) {

  fabric.Image.fromURL("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/7b3SLVgR65Fx4Q8JZyxQ", 
    function(oImg) {
      var canvas = $scope.canvas;
      canvas.clear().renderAll();
      canvas.add(oImg);
      $scope.$digest();
    });

});
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f61mshLj/)

**EDIT**:

Another approach is to use `setElement` on the fabric's image object:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var fabricImage;

  scope.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

  fabric.Image.fromURL("image1.png", function(oImg) {
    fabricImage = oImg;
    scope.canvas.add(oImg);
  });

  scope.$on('change', function(event, data) {
    if (!fabricImage) return;

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      fabricImage.setElement(image);
      scope.canvas.renderAll();
    }
    image.src = "image2.png";
  });

}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz0yv1zr/)

**EDIT 2:**

A third approach (probably the most straightforward) is to use `setSrc`:

```
  scope.$on('change', function(event, data) {
    if (!fabricImage) return;

    fabricImage.setSrc("image2.png",
          function(){
             scope.canvas.renderAll();
          });
  });
```

[updated fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/p72mzh2n/)

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue.  You're creating a new image rather than editing the src of the original image. If I have multiple images on the canvas, it will end up deleting those images as well.  I'm baffled why this issue is happening.  It has to be something with angular.  If I put this same code as straight js without angular, it doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Did you mean that `canvas.clear()` would delete them? Can you, otherwise, show the non-angular code that works?

Comment: I was wrong.  The same issue exists if done as straight js as well.  I've included that code in the post as well.

Comment: @user3527354, I added an alternative approach that works

Comment: Ok so the reason this issue happens is because renderAll() executes BEFORE the image finishes loading, so it's useless.  Then when you click on the blank image, it calls renderAll() again which is what corrects the issue.  So this could be corrected by calling renderAll() automatically after the image finishes loading.

Comment: New Dev, thanks for your help!  Your solution works and I actually found another solution using the setSrc method in fabricJS and calling renderAll in the callback function.  If you include the setSrc method in your solution as well, I'll go ahead and mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using object.setSrc, you have the option of specifying a callback.

http://jsfiddle.net/eg4y6d3k/9/

No object is selected initially, so I took out the canvas.getActiveObject() - Nothing was active.

`var tmp = $scope.canvas.getObjects();
tmp[0].setSrc( "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/7b3SLVgR65Fx4Q8JZyxQ", function(){$scope.canvas.renderAll()});`

The image changes when you click on the button.